# UWP How to bind listViewItem's visibility to section group dataContext?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp

I have a grouped CollectionViewSource binded to a ListView.  Each group header template has a button to collapse the section. Each item within the section can also be individually collapsed.  I'd like to bind listViewItem's visibility to the header's data context's Expanded property.

Object definitions:

```
public class InventoryHistorySectionModel : OnePlaceObservableSection<InventoryHistorySalesAreaModel>
    {
        public InventoryHistorySectionModel() { }
        public InventoryHistorySectionModel(List<InventoryHistorySalesAreaModel> items) : base(items) { }

        public InventoryHistorySectionType SectionType { get; set; }

        bool _expanded = true;
        public bool Expanded
        {
            get => _expanded;
            set
            {
                _expanded = value;
                CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
            }
        }

        public override event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    }

    public class InventoryHistorySalesAreaModel : OnePlaceObservableSection<SalesAreaEquipment>
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public int Priority { get; set; }

         bool _expanded = true;
        public bool Expanded
        {
            get => _expanded;
            set
            {
                _expanded = value;
                CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
            }
        }

        public override event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

        public new void Add(SalesAreaEquipment item)
        {
            item.SalesAreaId = Id;
            base.Add(item);
        }
    }

     public class OnePlaceObservableSection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, ISectionModel
    {
        public OnePlaceObservableSection() { }

        public OnePlaceObservableSection(IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            SetItems(items);
        }

        public void SetItems(IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            Clear();

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Add(item);
            }
        }

        public string HeaderTitle { get; set; }
    }
```

xaml:

```
<ListView 
                Grid.Row="2"
                x:Name="SectionList"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionSource}}"
                Margin="25,0,25,20"
                ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource InventoryHistoryItemSelector}"
                SelectionMode="None" 
                IsItemClickEnabled="False">
                
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding ElementName=GroupGrid, Path=DataContext.Expanded, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource DefaultListViewHeaderItemStyle}">
                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="classlib:InventoryHistorySectionModel">
                                <Grid Height="30" Tapped="ExpandGrid_Tapped" x:Name="GroupGrid">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <TextBlock
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Foreground="{StaticResource DefaultGrayTextColor}"
                                        Text="{x:Bind HeaderTitle, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                        Margin="15,0,0,0" 
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        FontFamily="{StaticResource DefaultFont}"
                                        FontSize="13"/>
                                    <Image 
                                        Grid.Column="1" 
                                        Source="{x:Bind Expanded, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ExpandableImageConverter}}" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                        Height="12.5" 
                                        Width="12.5"  
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </ListView.GroupStyle>
            </ListView>
```

I tried using the ItemContainerStyle and binding to a grid on the header to access its data context, but it doesn't seem to work.  I assume since there are multiple instances of the grid with the same name.
I tried propagating an expanded value down the object list but since each item in a section can also be individually collapsed, it didn't work out.

I was thinking I might solve this using a RelativeSource binding but i'm having trouble getting that to work as well.

EDIT:
I was able to solve this by changing around the object structures but I am still very curious if what I was attempting is possible.

Comment: Better to share an image about what you are trying to do

Comment: [The Windows Runtime doesn't support a Binding usage for `Setter.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.setter?view=winrt-22621#migration-notes). Direct binding `Expanded` in `ListView.ItemTemplate` is better if you can do all conversion on the code behind.